Historical stress scenarios for portfolio of short worst-of-basket structured products and short puts?
I'm looking for historical scenarios for stress testing considering a portfolio of SMI Index based instruments, particularly short structured products (predominantly autcallables and non-callable worst-of-basket products), short put options (EUREX) and long underlying positions.
As far as i understand these parameters seem to have a considerable impact on my portfolio:

Drop in underlying prices (Puts are exercised prematurely)
Increase in vola (puts nicrease in value, with short we are losing)
Lower interest rates (holding costs of options increase)
Increase in correlation (we are short correlation(?))
Negative correlation
Lower long-term vola and increased short-term vola
Lower dividends (we are long dividends (?)

My first question: Is my understanding of the impact of changes in parameters correct?
Second question: Which historical scenario relates to these points above?
Thank you in advance
Yours Thomas

Do you have access to Bloomberg (via BBA)? If so, DLIB allows you to price WO options fairly well. You don't need historical scenarios to answer your questions but if you want to, SHOC has plenty of preset (historical) scenarios you can use in DLIb (and all other pricing engines like OVME).

@Akdemy thank you! Excellent idea, I'll try it tomorrow. I didn't thought about that. Hope our license includes that.
